# wmctrl working as expected in terminal, but not as startup application

Tags: ubuntu, sh

A Shell Script to open a background VLC Player and a Shellscript to toggle the state of the DHCP Server and finally focus on the Terminal window works well when executed from a terminal, but fails when its executed from the Ubuntu Startup Applications.

Starter.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

/usr/bin/cvlc /var/www/stream.ts --sout '#rtp{dst=239.1.1.1,port=1234,mux=ts,ttl=1}' --loop >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
gnome-terminal --full-screen --title "DHCP" -e /home/user/dhcp.sh &
sleep 4
/usr/bin/wmctrl -a "DHCP"
```

and dhcp.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

INPUT=START
echo "*** DHCP-Server stopped. ***"  

while [ "$INPUT" != "SHUTDOWN" ]
do
read INPUT
if [ "$INPUT" = "START" ]; then 
    echo "*** DHCP-Server started. ***" 
    sudo service isc-dhcp-server start 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
fi;
if [ "$INPUT" = "STOP" ]; then
    echo "*** DHCP-Server stopped. ***"  
    sudo service isc-dhcp-server stop 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
fi;
done

#Shutdown
echo "*** Shutdown ***"  
sudo service isc-dhcp-server stop 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
sudo halt -p
exit 0
```

My programs are started, but the focusing part is not working.